# Issue with centering page in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I've been able to get the page to center in all browsers except IE which places the header and content divs to the left, while it centers the footer.

I'm new to CSS and just can't figure out why IE is different.  Any help would be appreciated!

http://www.ultralaboratories.com/index3.php

Answer (score 1):

IE needs the `DOCTYPE` specified, if it doesn't find it it renders the page in "quirks mode". In your html, the `DOCTYPE` is inside the `<head>`. Move it at the very top of the html, outside `<head>` and it should all be ok.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Mark it as an answer perhaps then :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have `<title>Ultra Labs</title>` at the beginning of the file. Please remove it and try